# How to disable or hide "Inspect views background.htm" from chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, hide, manifest

I'm trying to remove or disable "Inspect views background.htm" option from my Chrome extension, but it still appears. I can see some other extensions without  this option.

I tried uploading my extension to the webstore and installed from it, but still the option is visible. I googled for solution, but none found working.

My manifest is something like this;

```
{
"manifest_version":2,
"name":"extname",
"version": "1.0.1",
"icons": { "16": "icon16.png",
    "32": "icon32.png"
 },
    
"content_scripts":[
{
    "run_at": "document_start",
    "matches":["*://*.test.com/*","*://*.test2.com/*"],
    "js":["content.js"],
    "css":["style.css"]
}
],

"background":{
    "page": "background.htm",
    "persistent": true 
},
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon32.png"
},


"permissions":[
   
    "tabs",
    "storage",
    "https://www.test.com/*"
    
],

"externally_connectable": {
    "matches": ["*://*.test.com/*","*://*.test2.com/*"]
},

"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://www.gstatic.com/ https://*.firebaseio.com https://www.googleapis.com; object-src 'self'",

"web_accessible_resources": [
    "images/*.*"
  ]
}
```

Can anyone please point me in right direction, to disable or hide "Inspect views background.htm" option from the extension page? I really need to disable this option to prevent anyone from modifying the code and running. This should be possible because there are extensions without this link, but I'm unable to figure out how to do it.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The only method is to remove the background script and `background` section from manifest.json.

Comment: Note that even without a background script users can modify and inspect your code easily in devtools for other parts of an extension.